# Copy the selected object to clipboard VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, clipboard, sendkeys

i want to make an application that selects the focused Object where ever is

maybe in a browser or Explorer or any place

i think there is a function

> SendKeys.Send("^(c)")

but it does not work, any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your application cannot read the keyboard if another application has the focus. But if the external application is capable of copying to the clipboard, your application can access the object in the clipboard. One way to do this is with the .net `My.Computer.Clipboard` object.